# Best recommendation for doing active directory stuff with Python

Tags: python, active-directory

What is the best recommendation to work with Active directory using Python. 
I know I can go down the power shell route, and I am very rusty with power shell but slowly getting better with python.
My ask is basically what libraries or what would be the best method to modify/add/remove users in active directory using specifically python if possible. What is the best recommended method/library?

Would I use **PyAd** or **active_directory** libraries? What do you fine professionals recommend? Or do you know of any other libs, that would be better to use?
I am also planning on turning the script into a .exe using PyInstaller, in order to actually have this on the active directory machine/server. I am new to this approach, but feel more comfortable using Python than Powershell, although I am able to do what I want using powershell, if someone can help point me in the right direction with Python specifically I would really appreciate this.